# How to know if the asynchronous connection is working?

Tags: web-services, oracle, architecture, soa, oracle-soa

I am working on oracle SOA, I created a asynchrous connection and I was able to get the message that I was successful. Now as a client, how can I check if my service is working correctly. I am a newbie, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a *client* you don't. you can't, know the service is working.  That is the, um, magic of SOA.  You submit your request and just have to trust that the service will keep its side of the contact.

So, this service does something.  Eventually.  There must be some tangible output - an order placed, a password reset, a report generated.  At that point the service should communicate the outcome to the client by some mechanism depending on the nature of your application and the service in question - probably email or SMS, but perhaps a record in a table or a generated web page.

This it really a design or architectural question.  A Service is a *process*: there's a triggering action - the client's submission - and an outcome, which is what the client wants (or an exception).  In between is a set of business sub-routines which are largely invisible to the client (although a long running service might have windows, like Amazon's order tracking service).

You need to design your service so that it communicates the outcome to the client in some fashion.  The precise details will obviously depend on what your service does.